# Calling endpoint that i do not know until the user connects

Tags: angular

Please forgive me if I say anything incorrect I'm still quite green at angular.

The problem that I am running into is that I am running angular on a device that will be plugged into different networks and I have no idea what the IP address will be until it is plugged in. There are some endpoints that need to be hit that live on the same IP. The problem is that I cant figure out how to make it so that when the user opens the website the website knows what the IP is to make the request with. An idea I had is that the address that the user is going to type in is the IP that needs to be used for the request, is there a way to store this as something like a cookie and use it to form the request?

Is there a better way to do this or would this way even work? I know its a weird situation, if you need any more description of whats going on I can try my best to describe it better.

Comment: is this in a front end app, or something native like ionic? And do you need the network address of the local router, or the client's machine itself? If you're querying stuff on the client's machine, there's no need for an IP address.

Comment: I need the address of the local router, I have a Django rest api that I am trying to call living on the same address as where the angular is being served from